# Azure IOT Hub module / Environmental Variable

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-hub-device-management

Long road of learning, and wading through older documents, I finally deploying my IOT Edge module to IOT Hub using this command:

```
az iot edge set-modules --hubname xxx --device-Id yy --content ./deployment.arm64vf8.json
```

When I run this command, i review these screens:
[image]
[image]

However, **how do I set Environmental Variables from the JSON file**?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The environment variables are in `env` section of the deployment JSON.

Example:

```json
{
  "modulesContent": {
    "$edgeAgent": {
      "properties.desired.modules.EdgeModule": {
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "type": "docker",
        "status": "running",
        "restartPolicy": "always",
        "settings": {
          "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/samples:aspnetapp",
          "createOptions": "{\"PortBindings\":{\"80/tcp\":[{\"HostPort\":\"8080\"}]}}}"
        },
        "env": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": {
            "value": "Production"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Can you point me to the documentation please!

Is EdgModule you module name, or is it reserved name like system.Modules

Comment: I could not find the docs quickly myself, that is basically taken from our own files. EdgeModule is the module name.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that Intellisense put in the env key when I finally got to the right location in JSON.  Kills me that IOT tools would not present a form that allows for the proper configuration and setup of a schema file, which is a schema list.  Perhaps that was my first VS tool.  I also found that the only way to deploy the JSON is via the "az set edge set-models" statement.  Could easily incorporate that as well.  You using VSCode for that?